# Math expectation of the numerical sum

Tags: probability

We have a fair eight-sided die.
a.  Math expectation of a single roll:

My answer = 1 (.125) + 2 (.125) + 3 (.125) + 4 (.125) + 5 (.125) + 6 (.125) + 7 (.125) + 8 (.125)

b.  Math expectation of the numerical sum of 4 rolls.
My answer = (.125) * 4

c.  Math expectation of the numerical product of 5 rolls.
My answer = (.125)^5

Are my answers correct?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Part $a)$ is correct. You get that the math expectation of a single roll is $9/2.$ You should use this value to solve $b)$ and $c)$ instead of $1/8.$

So the solution of $b)$ is $4\cdot \frac{9}{2}=18$ and the solution of $c)$ is $\left(\frac{9}{2}\right)^5.$

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant to type.